# Cakephp - random select from the database and View

Tags: cakephp, select, view, random

I need create three random links to other posts, in my post view function.

Controller:

```
$random = $this->Post->find('all', array( 
             'order' => 'rand()',
             'limit' => 3,
             'conditions' => array('Post.status' => 'ok') 
             ));
```

But i do not know, how to write a foreach for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It will depend on the fields you get back from Post. I would change the **controller** code just slightly to this:

```
$this->set('random_posts', $this->Post->find('all', array( 
   'conditions' => array('Post.status' => 'ok'), 
   'order' => 'rand()',
   'limit' => 3,
)));
```

Then in the **view** you cycle through them in the foreach:

```
<?php 
foreach ($random_posts as $random_post) {
    echo $this->Html->link($random_post['Post']['name'], array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $random_post['Post']['id']));
}
?>
```

Be sure to update the fields in the HTML link to those that conform to what ever comes back from the Post model.

Answer (score 1):

On my local machine this code is working but on live server it generates random id just once, after that repeats the same id

```
$max =
  $this->Article->find('first',
                       array('conditions'=>array('Article.status'=>'Active'),
                       'order' => 'rand()'));
```